# Vaadin Calendar - adding event on single click

Tags: java, vaadin

Can I add an event to the calendar by clicking anywhere inside it (weekly view)? Is it possible to get just the exact date of the click, like event.getStart() / event.getEnd() in rangeSelect() while dragging the mouse? It doesn't seem like any built-in handler supports that.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin provide the CalendareEvent event. event.getStrat()/event.getEnd() is provided Please refer the documents provided by Vaadin.

Comment: I know, it was just an example. I'd like to get the event's start date just by clicking once, without dragging.